The canonical identification of the orthogonal symplectic group
$\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$We have the identification of $\Sp(n) \cap O(2n,\mathbb{R})$ with $U(n, \mathbb{C})$, where
$$
\Sp(n)= \{A: A^T J A = J\}
\;\text{ with }\;J = \begin{bmatrix}
0_n & I_n \\
-I_n & 0_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
To see this, note that the restriction of the map
$$
\iota : M(n, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow  M(2n, \mathbb{R}),\;\text{ with }\;\iota(A+iB)= \begin{bmatrix}
A & -B \\
B & A
\end{bmatrix}, $$ to $ U(n, \mathbb{C})$ gives an isomorphism between $U(n, \mathbb{C})$ and $\Sp(n) \cap O(2n,\mathbb{R})$.
Now say we replace $J$ with
$$
J' = \begin{bmatrix}
0_n & D \\
-D & 0_n
\end{bmatrix},
$$ where $D$ is a non-singular diagonal matrix, and denote $G_D= \{A: A^T J' A = J'\}$. 
Question. Is there a canonical identification of $G_D \cap O(2n,\mathbb{R})$?

I apologise for my previous incorrect answer - it was the result of a simple algebra mistake.
I provide a partial answer which works in the cases where a normal matrix commuting with $D^2$ implies it commutes with $D$, this is the case when $D$ has only positive entries, or when there are no elements of $D$ which have equal magnitude and opposite sign.
Write the special orthogonal matrix out in blocks as
\begin{align}
   R = \begin{pmatrix}w & x\\y&z\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
we have the relations
\begin{align}
    R R^T &= I\\RJ^\prime R^T&= J^\prime ,
\end{align}
combining these to obtain $R = J^{-1} R J$ yields
\begin{align}
    y &= -D^{-1} x D\\z &= D^{-1} w D,
\end{align}
Then from $J^\prime R = R J^\prime$ we obtain
\begin{align}
   \begin{pmatrix}0&D\\-D&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}w &x\\-D^{-1} x D&D^{-1} w D\end{pmatrix} &=\begin{pmatrix}w &x\\-D^{-1} x D&D^{-1} w D\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&D\\-D&0\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}-xD &wD\\-Dw&-Dx\end{pmatrix} &=\begin{pmatrix}-xD &wD\\-D^{-1} w D^2&-D^{-1} x D^2\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
from the bottom row we can read that $x$ and $w$ commute with $D^2$. If (in addition!) $x$ and $w$ commute with $D$ then
\begin{align}
    R = \begin{pmatrix}w &x \\-x&w\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
is a symplectic (and orthogonal matrix) and is such that the complex unitary matrix $w+ix$ commutes with $D$, in other words $G_D \cap \mathcal{O}(2n,\mathbb{R}) $ may be identified with the subgroup of the unitary group with commutes with $D$.
Edit: I think the above discussion generalises cleanly to cases where $D$ contains negative elements as well. All you do is wrap everything above in the similarity transformation $x\mapsto P x P^T$ where $P$ is the permutation which swaps all the negative elements of $D$ in the top right of $J^\prime$ with their corresponding elements in $-D$ in the bottom left.

I think it's also acceptable behaviour to edit and undelete an answer, if it hasn't already received any votes or comments.
